# Get part from python output string in flask

Tags: javascript, python, bash

Just join to this community. I have python script that produce string in html :

```
from shelljob import proc
import flask
import os
import eventlet

eventlet.monkey_patch()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/create')
def create():
    g = proc.Group()
    p = g.run("timeout 30s mycommand | grep -Eo 'https?://\S+'")

    def read_process():
        while g.is_pending():
            lines = g.readlines()
            for proc, line in lines:
                yield "data:" + line + "\n\n"

    return flask.Response( read_process(), mimetype= 'text/event-stream' )

@app.route('/')
def get_page():
    return flask.send_file('page.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

that code will produce something like :

```
This sample output with static result...
Please visit https://www.example.com/click?nonce=1a2b3c4d to bla bla bla.
This sample output with static result...
Please visit https://www.example.com/click?nonce=1a2b3c4d to bla bla bla.
```

How i can get url only like this one and only show first result :

```
https://www.example.com/click?nonce=1a2b3c4d
```

because if i type"**timeout 30s mycommand | grep -Eo 'https?://\S+'**" i can get exact url.
I can replace the text with javascript, but i'm still got list result instead 1 line. This my html "page.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">.urldb{color: #ffffff;padding: 10px;background: red;text-decoration: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-linkify/2.1.4/linkify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-linkify/2.1.4/linkify-string.min.js"></script>
<script>
var source = new EventSource("/create");
var options = {className: 'urldb',target: {url: '_blank'}};
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += event.data.replace(/(\bhttps?:\/\/\S+)|[^]/g, '$1').linkify(options) + "<br/>";
    if (event.data.indexOf('Welcome') > -1) {
        $("#output").hide();
        window.location.href = "https://example.com";
    }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using that script i got result like :

```
https://www.example.com/click?nonce=1a2b3c4d
https://www.example.com/click?nonce=1a2b3c4d
https://www.example.com/click?nonce=1a2b3c4d
```

Thanks and sorry if any wrong in my question.

---

Edit to add more alternative wrong in python or javascript and remove "e" to make clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have maybe typo in the pattern. Change `https?://e\S+` to `https?://\S+` (remove `e`) and it works.

For output only fist match you can use `-m1`. For more informations see [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Comment: it still produce like my sample even i remove e ("timeout 30s mycommand | grep -Eo -m1 'https?://\S+'") i think this problem from my python code and not in bash part.. but don't know where.. and thanks for your replay..